# XOR operation for two characters

Tags: c, char, xor

Here I am trying to swap two characters in a string using XOR operation. But GCC compiler throws me a `segmentation fault`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "welcome";

    str[0] = str[0] ^ str[1];  // Segmenation fault here
    str[1] = str[0] ^ str[1];
    str[0] = str[1] ^ str[0]; 

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, the compiler doesn't not "throw [you] a segmentation fault". It happens at run time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change literals in C. `str` points to read-only memory.

Try instead:

```
char str[] = "welcome";
```

There is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html) on the subject.

Comment: i knew I should have posted an answer instead of a comment! ;) +1

Comment: I'm sure you could also find hundreds of SO answers on the subject.

Comment: That's true, this question gets posted a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`str` points to a string literal. String literals are read only. Try:

```
char str[] = "welcome";
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `char*` actually points to a constant. I.e., you are trying to modify something stored in the constant data part of your program.

```
 char* str = strdup("welcome");
```

Comment: `strdup` is overkill for these purposes, and leaves you responsible for `free`ing something that you might not have expected.